# Getting undefined components in React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Just upgraded to `react-router-dom 4.0.0`. All my components are either regular `class`es or fat arrows. They are all exported using `export default ThatComponent`. Yet I'm getting this:

*Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) **but got: undefined.** You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Router`.*

```
// minimal showcase
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss } from 'react-router';

const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      {/* both Match and Miss components below cause an error */}
      <Match exactly pattern="/login" component={Login} /> 
      <Match exactly pattern="/frontpage" component={Frontpage} />
      <Match exactly pattern="/logout" render={() => (<div>logout</div>)} />
      <Miss component={NoMatch} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Why do the `<Match>` components think the other components are undefined?

Comment: Can you share where you found the Match component?

Comment: Got it from here: http://frontend.turing.io/lessons/react-router-4.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the final release of `react-router` there is no `Match` nor `Miss`. You just need to use `Route`. Also, you need to install and *import* `react-router-dom` package to use `BrowserRouter` (see [React Router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)).

To make your example work with minimal changes, you'd need to do the following:

```js
// minimal showcase
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} /> 
            <Route exact path="/frontpage" component={Frontpage} />
            <Route exact path="/logout" render={() => (<div>logout</div>)} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Please have a look at [NoMatchExample in React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match) to see how to and when to use `Switch`.

Answer (score 1):

Check source of react-router here: https://unpkg.com/react-router@4.0.0/index.js（also https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.0.0/index.js）,
There is no **Match** under it. **Match** maybe belong to other package.

Comment: Hmm… this is where I got it from: http://frontend.turing.io/lessons/react-router-4.html Maybe it was just a part of RR4 alpha which didn't make it into the current build.